# calculation of correlation time?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, function

I have two time series of a two realizations of a random process, the process fluctuate around an average so i consider that is a ergodic process. I compute the time correlation function, but i need the characteristic time scale, better known as the correlation time, but i don't know how, This time characterizes the time for time correlation function decay to zero.

I tried to fit a curve, but the resulting time its too big, so i think its not the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two definitions of correlation time that I know of. Each focusses on fitting a different part of the function.

One way is to expand the function around tau=0 to second order (i.e. an upside down parabola). After factoring out the variance, the time is rescaled by stddev(x)/stddev(dx/dt) and this scaling factor is called the differential correlation time. This measure focusses on the curvature around 0.

Another definition focusses more on the decay of the tails by fitting them with exponential functions whose decay time is then called the correlation time. In the case that there is only power law decay, no characteristic correlation time exists.